@Value annotaion not picking up the values from spring profiles application properties
New to Spring Profiles. I have created two profiles product-dev.properties and customer-dev.properties in local git repository
product-dev.properties :-
product.details.name=dev-product
product.details.quantity=200
product.details.price=150.0

customer-dev.properties :-
customer.details.name=dev-customer
customer.details.age=20
customer.details.email=dev@gmail.com

Then, created a config server with correct path to the repository. In Config client, I've defined spring.profiles.active and spring.profiles.include.
config client application.properties:-
spring.application.name=client-service
server.port=8080
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.profiles.include=product-dev,customer-dev
spring.config.import=configserver:

logging.level.org.springframework.boot.context.config=DEBUG

But, when I tried to get the product or customer values from the profiles using @Value annotation like this -
@Value("${product.details.name}")

I am getting this error:
Caused by: org.springframework.util.PlaceholderResolutionException: Could not resolve placeholder 'product.details.name' in value "${product.details.name}"
    at org.springframework.util.PlaceholderResolutionException.withValue(PlaceholderResolutionException.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.util.PlaceholderParser$ParsedValue.resolve(PlaceholderParser.java:416) ~[spring-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.util.PlaceholderParser.replacePlaceholders(PlaceholderParser.java:128) ~[spring-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:118) ~[spring-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:114) ~[spring-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:255) ~[spring-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:226) ~[spring-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:201) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:963) ~[spring-beans-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1541) ~[spring-beans-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1519) ~[spring-beans-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:785) ~[spring-beans-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768) ~[spring-beans-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509) ~[spring-beans-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    ... 22 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0

When I tried to get the profile details using http url - localhost/<application-name>/<profile>, I am getting the correct output.
localhost:8888/customer/dev :-
{"name": "customer","profiles": ["dev"],"label": null,"version": "ea6c7e6e30d2042352858fe132ddecd47f8b01a1","state": "","propertySources": [{"name": "/Users/MA20465963/Downloads/MS_Assignment2/config-repo-files/customer-dev.properties","source": {"customer.details.name": "dev-customer","customer.details.age": "20","customer.details.email": "dev@gmail.com"}}]}

localhost:8888/product/dev :-
{"name": "product","profiles": ["dev"],"label": null,"version": "ea6c7e6e30d2042352858fe132ddecd47f8b01a1","state": "","propertySources": [{"name": "/Users/MA20465963/Downloads/MS_Assignment2/config-repo-files/product-dev.properties","source": {"product.details.name": "dev-product","product.details.quantity": "200","product.details.price": "150.0"}}]}

That means the profile specific property files are loaded correctly. But, I don't understand the reason why can't I get the values using @Value annotation.

The idea how Spring is picking profile specific files is related to below file naming convention: application-{profile}.properties. 
application is coming from default value of spring.application.name property. In your case you have overriden spring.application.name with client-service.
Try to rename your propertiy file ex: customer-dev.properties ->
client-service-customer-dev.properties and check if for localhost:8888/client-service/customer-dev it will include expected properties.

Thanks a lot...it worked
